# pymongo insert_many result from insert

Tags: python, database, pymongo

pymongo result from insert_many ?

I enter several documents via insert_many, this works very well. But now I would like to know which documents were entered into the database with insert_many, because I created an index and need the option unique=True.

```
myCollection.create_index([("linkhash", pymongo.ASCENDING)], unique=True)
```

does anyone have an idea how to return only the records that were really inserted into the collection by insert_many ?

```
try:
    results = myCollection.insert_many(pickle_raw_new, ordered=False)
   
except pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError as e:
    pass
finally:
    count_after_insert = myDB.get_collection("collED").estimated_document_count()
    count_result = count_after_insert - count_before_insert
 
    if count_before_insert != count_after_insert:
        print("Es wurden", count_result, "Datensätze der Collection hinzugefügt")
    else:
        print("Es wurden keine Datensätze hinzugefügt")
```

Comment: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.InsertManyResult